# Date calculations

Tags: calculations, datetime

I'm building a LaTeX document that helps me to formulate quotations for my customers.
Since I decided to offer monthly recurring payments I'd like to have payment dates calculated automatically starting from a specific one.
Say, for example, that you have:

`\today{}`

then I need to have:

- `\today` +30 days
- `\today` +60 days
- `\today` +180 days

and so on...

Is that possible?

**EDIT**: I ended up using the package `advdate` because I obtained a more compact result to do this:

```
% Payment starts in 4 months.
\AdvMonth{4}

% 1 chunk per month -> due date:
\begin{enumerate*}
    \AdvMonth{1} \item due date: \textbf{\today}
        ...
\end{enumerate*}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See the [advdate](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/advdate) package.

**Edit** Six years later, I am finally getting around to adding an example.  It does what the package says it does.

> `\AdvanceDate` Advances date the specified number of days [an argument in square brackets, defaulting to 1] and sets the result to `\today`

Two things to notice there:

- To advance by 30 days, for instance, the syntax is `\AdvanceDate[30]`.
- The package effectively uses `\today` as a variable.  Which means if you are recording several dates relative to today, you need to advance incrementally.  If you want 30 days, then 60 days, you need to call `\AdvanceDate[30]` twice.
- Of course, TeX's scoping rules are still in effect.  So if you advance `\today` in a group, the changes end when the group ends.  So if you make a table your increments are forgotten at the end of each cell.

Here is an example document, showing both of these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\begin{document}
Today is: \today

Tomorrow is: \DayAfter

30 days from today is \AdvanceDate[30]\today.

60 days from today is \AdvanceDate[30]\today.

180 days from today is \AdvanceDate[120]\today.
\AdvanceDate[-180]
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|cc|}\hline
    Relative description & Date \\\hline
    today & \today \\
    tomorrow & \DayAfter \\
    30 days from today & \AdvanceDate[30]\today\\
    60 days from today & \AdvanceDate[60]\today\\
    180 days from today & \AdvanceDate[180]\today\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe output]

Comment: This answer would benefit from an example.

Answer (score 24):

This is possible with the [datenumber](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datenumber) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}

\begin{document}

\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{30}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
In 30 days is \datedate

\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{60}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
In 60 days is \datedate

\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{90}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
In 90 days is \datedate

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: +1 But I still need that the first date is parametric, not just from today.

Comment: @microspino, if you run `texdoc datenumber` on a command line, you'll find out about a command `\setdatenumber` to start from arbitrary dates.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible with the [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[calc,useregional]{datetime2}
\newcount\myct
\newcount\datecount
\newcommand{\myday}[1]{%
    \DTMsavenow{mydate}
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{mydate}{#1}{\myct}
    \DTMsavejulianday{mydate}{\number\myct}
    \DTMusedate{mydate}
}

\begin{document}

\today~ is the day

In 10 days is  \myday{10}

In 30 days is  \myday{30}

In 90 days is  \myday{90}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. The only answer that does not use the old `datetime` and `advdate` packages.