# Add (n) working days to a specific date

Tags: calculations, datetime

My `g-brief` will contain something like "I have noted a deadline for your answer of ten working days until...".

Is there a package or way to add `n` working-days (ie. mon-fri, let's not over complicate things with holidays etc ;) to todays date programmatically?

[I have found an approximate solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/date-calculations) in the `datenum` and `advdate` packages:

```
\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{10}
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}
```

But this "only"* adds the days, not taking into account if a day is a working day or a free day (ie. weekend).

*In the humble *"I couldn't have done anything remotely like this myself (so I'm thankful for it), but it doesn't quite fit my need and possibly could be tweaked"*-way.

Comment: see the following question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/date-calculations

Comment: If you are only worried about 10 days, isn't this always 2 weeks, and you can just add 14 normal days?

Comment: @cslstr  Not if you start on a weekend.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Exactly - I don't know when the letter will be written.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen That just happens to be the question I linked in my question ;) There they talk about "plain" days-of-week, not taking into account the specific "working days".

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't see the "workday" requirement. The `scrdate` package can tell you the weekday for a specific date. I guess that and `advdate` could bring a suitable way (it's beyond my knowledge)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `pgfcalendar` package (part of the [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) bundle.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}

\newcount\julianday
\newcount\daycount
\newcount\weekday

\newcommand*{\adddays}[2]{%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\julianday}%
  \daycount=#2\relax
  \loop
    \advance\julianday by 1\relax
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\julianday}{\weekday}%
    \ifnum\weekday<5\relax
      % It's a weekday (Mon-Fri)
      \advance\daycount by -1\relax
    \fi
  \ifnum\daycount > 0
  \repeat
  \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\julianday}{\thisyear}{\thismonth}{\thisday}%
  \thisyear-\thismonth-\thisday
}

\begin{document}

10 working days from
\the\year-\the\month-\the\day\ (today):
\adddays{\year-\month-\day}{10}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: 10 working days from 2014-4-16 (today): 2014-04-30]

You can adapt this to take holidays into account:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcount\julianday
\newcount\daycount
\newcount\weekday

\newcommand*{\holiday}[2]{%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\julianday}%
  \csdef{holiday-\number\julianday}{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\adddays}[2]{%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\julianday}%
  \daycount=#2\relax
  \loop
    \advance\julianday by 1\relax
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\julianday}{\weekday}%
    \ifnum\weekday<5\relax
      % It's a weekday (Mon-Fri)
      \ifcsdef{holiday-\number\julianday}%
      {% It's a holiday
      }%
      {% Not a holiday
        \advance\daycount by -1\relax
      }%
    \fi
  \ifnum\daycount > 0
  \repeat
  \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\julianday}{\thisyear}{\thismonth}{\thisday}%
  \thisyear-\thismonth-\thisday
}

\holiday{2014-04-21}{Easter Monday}
\holiday{2014-05-05}{Early May Bank Holiday}

\begin{document}

10 working days from
\the\year-\the\month-\the\day\ (today):
\adddays{\year-\month-\day}{10}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: 10 working days from 2014-4-16 (today): 2014-05-01]

Comment: **You** are the goddess of LaTeX. Thank you! I have added a little variable `\newcommand{\FristinWerktagen}{10}` ("DeadlineInWorkingDays") which I define at the top and in your command and I have turned `\thisyear-\thismonth-\thisday` into `\thisday.\thismonth.\thisyear` (my inner nerd prefers the first, but real people need to read this ;) and it's perfect. Again, Thank you!

Comment: That goddess-comment might be read wrongly. You know what I mean.

Comment: @Christian LOL :-)

Comment: @Christian One day I'll finish my new LaTeX book which has a chapter on using `pgfcalendar`. At the moment I only have an incomplete draft version available at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/admin-report-draft.pdf

Comment: If that is considered an "incomplete draft" the finished product will be amazing. PS. The @-Thingie doesn't work with your name for me. Time to head to some meta stackexchange site... Happy easter!