# Advancing \today by x days

Tags: datetime, advdate

New LaTex user here, hoping you can help me.

I am drafting a letter, the submission date of which I do not yet know. For this reason I am dating it using `\today`. However, in the text of the letter, I would like to specify a date two weeks in advance of `\today`. In other words, there is an [advance date] and an [advance date II], the latter specifying a date 14 days after the former.

I found the `advdate` package but, unless I am mistaken, it doesn't allow for setting two individual hypothetical dates. Is there a non-complicated way of implementing this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @percusse: The question you linked is about a `\tomorrow` command, but this post is about a `\fortnight or a double `\fortnight` command ;-). It is related, for sure, but not a duplicate.

Comment: See also [Add (n) working days to a specific date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171823/add-n-working-days-to-a-specific-date) and [Date calculations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/date-calculations).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You can add or subtract as many as you want instead of +1. It's just the name of the macro it is not limited to *tomorrow* per se

Answer (score 15):

The package `advdate` provides the command `\AdvanceDate[]` with an optional argument, defaulting to `1` (day). However, it changes the date output by `\today`. This can be prevented by using a new command, say `\advanceday` and using a group inside, such that registers are changed only locally, this is shown in the output, where the second call to `\today` (after the first call to `\advanceday` still shows the current date (9th of July 2014), so it is not affected by `\advanceday` outside!

I used an optional argument to `\advanceday`, defaulting to 14 days and added a command `\evenmoreadvanceday`, with optional argument defaulting to 28 days, but actually, `\evenmoreadvanceday` is redundant, since `\advancedays[28]` does the same job. It is rather meant to make the second date more outstanding in the code.

You can change the output format of `\today` by usage of `datetime` package and its various options/commands (not done in here)

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{advdate}

\newcommand{\advanceday}[1][14]{%
\begingroup
\AdvanceDate[#1]%
\today%
\endgroup
}%

\newcommand{\evenmoreadvanceday}[1][28]{%
\advanceday[#1]%
}%


\begin{document}

Today is \today~and in 14 days it is \advanceday, but today is still \today~and in 28 days it is \evenmoreadvanceday%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Christian Hupfer! I'm not sure how or why, but it works!

Comment: @foucalt: If you have questions about the code, just ask ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A variation of `advdate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}% Needed for \IfStrEqCase
\usepackage{datenumber}% Date formatting
\usepackage{advdate}% Needed for \AdvanceDate
\usepackage{pgf}% For math

\newcounter{dateOffset}%
\newcommand*{\SetDateOffsetForNext}[1]{%
\pgfmathsetcounter{dateOffset}{7-int(\the\value{datedayname})}% Initialize
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
    {mon}{\pgfmathsetcounter{dateOffset}{int(mod(\the\value{dateOffset}+8,14))}}%
    }[\PackageError{\SetDateOffsetForNext}{Do not know "#1" as day of week}{}]%
    \IfEq{\the\value{dateOffset}}{0}{\pgfmathsetcounter{dateOffset}{7}}{}%
}%

\newcommand*{\PrintDateForNext}[1]{%
    \SetDateOffsetForNext{#1}% Determine date offset
    \AdvanceDate[\value{dateOffset}]% Advance to specified day
    \today% Print specified date
    \AdvanceDate[-\value{dateOffset}]% Restore current day
    is #1day 2 weeks later% debug output
}

\begin{document}
Today is \today\par
\PrintDateForNext{mon}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting, but if I understood correctly your code, you can only compute what date is next Monday, right?

Comment: After 2 weeks (14 days)

Comment: I appreciate other solutions too, but I do not understand why you restricted your solution to Mondays? (Using `\PrintDateForNext{tue}` fails with compilation error, for example) The specific day of week is basically completely irrelevant. Only the relative day shift of 14 (or whatever) days is of importance.

Comment: @subhamsoni: It is customary to provide a link to where you got the original code from: [Insert relative date and time specifications?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31762/4301).