# Generate a sequence of dates in LaTeX

Tags: counters, datetime

In LaTeX, I'd like to generate a sequence of dates, which repeats on Monday and Wednesday every week. The sequence should look like:

```
Mon 3/30
Wed 4/1
Mon 4/6
Wed 4/8
...
```

I have tried to use the datenumber package in LaTeX but to no avail. I would appreciate any help how to approach this problem. Thank you!

I have tested the program below:

```
\setdate{2015}{3}{30}
\newcommand{\pnext}{%
\thedateyear/%
\ifnum\value{datemonth}<10 0\fi
\thedatemonth/%
\ifnum\value{dateday}<10 0\fi
\thedateday%
%\addtocounter{dateday}{1}
\setcounter{dateday}{4}
\nextdate
}
\pnext, \pnext, \pnext, \pnext, \pnext
```

However, the output is:

2015/03/30 , 2015/03/05 , 2015/03/05 , 2015/03/05 , 2015/03/05

Comment: Perhaps you could post a small document showing exactly what you tried and how it didn't work?

Comment: This might be a duplicate: [Advancing `\today` by x days](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188736/5764)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using [`advdate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/advdate) to `adv`ance `date`s:

> March 30, 2015
>   April 2, 2015
>   April 6, 2015
>   April 9, 2015
>   April 13, 2015
>   April 16, 2015

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

\newif\iffirst
\newcommand{\pnext}{%
  \AdvanceDate[3]% Step 3 days ahead...
  \iffirst
    \AdvanceDate\global\firstfalse% ...maybe 4
  \else
    \global\firsttrue
  \fi
  \today
}

\begin{document}

\ThisYear{2015}\ThisMonth{3}\ThisDay{30}% Set date to March 30, 2015
\today\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the output of `\today` by reading up on [Date format in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31137/5764).

Comment: @jackyd: I've updated the answer slightly to use an alternating step (3 or 4 days). In your case, you're probably interested in a 2-day/5-day stepping pattern to retrieve a Mon/Wed schedule.