# Create sequence of dates in a table

Tags: datetime, advdate

I would like to create a sequence of dates with weekly increments, which should be shown in a table environment.

I've been fiddling around with a code snippet posted in this forum ([Generate a sequence of dates in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236078/generate-a-sequence-of-dates-in-latex)) which uses advdate for this purpose. However, when you use the commands inside a table environment, the date is no longer incremented.

Here you can see a minimal working example which shows the problem. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

\newif\iffirst
\newcommand{\pnext}{%
  \AdvanceDate[7]% Step 3 days ahead...
  \iffirst
    \AdvanceDate\global\firstfalse% ...maybe 4
  \else
    \global\firsttrue
  \fi
  \today
}

\begin{document}

\ThisYear{2015}\ThisMonth{3}\ThisDay{30}

%The output of the following sequence is correct:
\today\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext

%However, it no longer works when the date is used in a table environment.
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
\today\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a direct solution but I do exactly this with the `datenumber` package. I can post a solution using that package if you like.

Comment: I could do with any solution! I would greatly appreciate yours. I have fiddled around with the  `datenumber` package, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using essentially the same code, but with the `datenumber` package, this works fine in both tables and outside of tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\newif\iffirst
\newcommand{\pnext}{%
    \addtocounter{datenumber}{3}%
    \iffirst
        \addtocounter{datenumber}{1}%
        \global\firstfalse
    \else
        \global\firsttrue
    \fi
    \setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
    \datedate
}

\begin{document}

\setdatenumber{2015}{3}{30}
%The output of the following sequence is correct:
\datedate\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par
\pnext\par


%And it’s also correct in a table
\setdatenumber{2015}{3}{30}
\firstfalse
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
\datedate\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: A little problem: When trying to get a weekly sequence, it wrongly jumps from Oct 29 to Nov 6: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\newif\iffirst
\newcommand{\pnext}{%
    \addtocounter{datenumber}{7}%
    \iffirst
        \addtocounter{datenumber}{1}%
        \global\firstfalse
    \else
        \global\firsttrue
    \fi
    \setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
    \datedate
}

\begin{document}
\setdatenumber{2015}{10}{22}
\firstfalse
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
\datedate\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext\\
\pnext
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}`

Comment: Even though this is surely not a problem of your script but a `datenumber` problem, you don't, by any chance, have an idea how to get a proper weekly sequence?

Comment: @Thomas if you are incrementing by 7 days, you should eliminate all the conditional code entirely.  So to increment by 7 you need only `\addtocounter{datenumber}{7}\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}\datedate`

Comment: Belated congrats on joining the 100K club!!