# Advdate in tables does not advance date correctly

Tags: tables, datetime, advdate

I am writing a syllabus that has the course schedule in a table. I am using the `\AdvanceDate` command in the `\advdate` package to advance the date by two or five days. This works fine outside a table. Inside a table, it continues to advance relative to the original value of `\today` set by the `\SetDate` command instead of the value of `\today` updated by the `\AdvanceDate` command.

In other words, inside a table, `\AdvanceDate` acts like `\DayAfter`, which always resets `\today`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{advdate}

\newdateformat{mydate}{\THEDAY\ \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]}

\begin{document}

\SetDate[23/08/2016] 

\mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[2] \mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[5] \mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[2] \mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[5] \mydate\today

\medskip

In table format:

\SetDate[23/08/2016] 

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}

\mydate\today \\

\AdvanceDate[2]\mydate\today \\

\AdvanceDate[5]\mydate\today \\

\AdvanceDate[2]\mydate\today \\

\AdvanceDate[5]\mydate\today \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264232/create-sequence-of-dates-in-a-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each cell within a `tabular` creates a group within which the scope of changes are limited. In this particular case, the date advancement doesn't survive the scope of the cell, meaning it reverts back to the original value when you move to the next row (or cell).

You can update the definition of `\AdvanceDate` to make a `\global` change to  `\day`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime,advdate}

\newdateformat{mydate}{\THEDAY\ \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AdvanceDate[1][\@ne]{\global\advance\day#1 \FixDate}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\SetDate[23/08/2016] 

\mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[2] \mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[5] \mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[2] \mydate\today

\AdvanceDate[5] \mydate\today

\medskip

In table format:

\SetDate[23/08/2016] 

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}

  \mydate\today \\

  \AdvanceDate[2]\mydate\today \\

  \AdvanceDate[5]\mydate\today \\

  \AdvanceDate[2]\mydate\today \\

  \AdvanceDate[5]\mydate\today

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation of the problem and then solving it.

Comment: If I add `\mydate\today` at the very end (just before `\end{document}`, I get the 37 August. Based on your explanation, I assume that is because the `\FixDate` command also doesn't survive the scope of the cell. Is there an easy fix?

Comment: @mimuller: Yes. Try [this version](https://pastebin.com/raw/7pVPQweM) which does a `\global\advance` of all counters (`\day`, `\month` and `\year`), adding zero (`\z@`). This then fixes the date globally.