# How to calculate future dates based on custom date (e.g. 2018-05-05 + 14 days)?

Tags: datetime, date, advdate, datenumber, date-calculations

I want to create invoices for customers in `scrlttr2`. Hereby I set the document date via `\setkomavar{date}{\today}`.

I reuse this date with [advdate](https://ctan.org/pkg/advdate?lang=de) to automatically add a payment deadline into the letter foot (deadline = *todays date* + *14 days in future*).

This is working completely fine if only using `\today` as the documents date (see MWE).

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{advdate}

\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\begin{document}
Today is \today. Please pay until \AdvanceDate[14]\today.
\end{document}
```

---

However, I also want to use custom dates, e.g. 2018-05-05 as the document date. Do you have any idea on how to generate the mentioned payment deadline based on arbitrary dates instead of `\today` only?

In best case I could insert `\today` as well as `2018-05-05` into the `\setkomavar{date}`-command, so the following example should add 14 days to my custom date (when using custom dates) but to `\today`'s date as well (in case of using `\today` as the document date):

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{advdate}

\setkomavar{date}{2018-05-05}

\begin{document}
Today is \today. Please pay until \AdvanceDate[14]\date.
\end{document}
```

---

**Maybe helpful packages are:**

- [advdate](https://ctan.org/pkg/advdate?lang=de) (it seems like this only works for `\today`)
- [datenumber](https://ctan.org/pkg/datenumber) (difficult to use without `\today`)
- [datetime](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime) or [datetime2](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) (also easiest to use with `\today`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all there is a difference between `\today` and the content of the variable `date`. Setting the variable `date` does not change `\today`. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\begin{document}
% default value of date variable is \today
Today is \today{} and the variable date stores \usekomavar{date}.

% changing value for variable date does not change \today!
\setkomavar{date}{2018-05-05}
Today is \today{} and the date variable stores \usekomavar{date}.
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

---

Package `advdate` provides the additional commands `\SaveDate`, `\SetDate` and `\DayAfter` (see the package documentation), which can be used to get the desired result.

First of all we save todays date as dd/mm/yyyy (this syntax is used by all macros of `advdate`) in the macro `\invoicedate`.

```
% Save dd/mm/yyyy for today
\newcommand*\invoicedate{}
\SaveDate[\invoicedate]
```

`\invoicedate` then will be used to set the set the KOMA-Script variable `date` and a new variable `paymentdate` automatically. You do not have to set or change these variables manually!

```
\setkomavar{date}{{\SetDate[\invoicedate]\today}}
\newkomavar{paymentdate}
\setkomavar{paymentdate}{{\SetDate[\invoicedate]\DayAfter[14]}}
```

Only if you want to set a fixed value for variable `date` (and the depending variable `paymentdate`) you have to use the following macro`\setinvoicedate`. Note that this macro changes `\invoicedate` **and** sets the KOMA-Scripts variables `date` and `paymentdate` automatically. So you only have to use this macro for a diffent invoice/letter date.

```
\newcommand*\setinvoicedate[1]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{today}
    {\SaveDate[\invoicedate]}%
    {\renewcommand*\invoicedate{#1}}%
}
```

The syntax the is `\setinvoicedate{dd/mm/yyyy}`. Example:

```
\setinvoicedate{24/12/2018}
```

You can use `\setinvoicedate` several times in a document, ie if you have more than one invoice in your document. If you want to reset the invoice/letter date to todays date, you can use

```
\setinvoicedate{today}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{advdate}

% Save dd/mm/yyyy for today
\newcommand*\invoicedate{}
\SaveDate[\invoicedate]

\setkomavar{date}{{\SetDate[\invoicedate]\today}}
\newkomavar{paymentdate}
\setkomavar{paymentdate}{{\SetDate[\invoicedate]\DayAfter[14]}}

% should be possible to use a different invoicedate
\newcommand*\setinvoicedate[1]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{today}
    {\SaveDate[\invoicedate]}%
    {\renewcommand*\invoicedate{#1}}%
}
% set a different invoice date
% syntax: \setinvoicedate{dd/mm/yyyy}
% if it should be reset to \today use \setinvoicedate{today}
\setinvoicedate{24/12/2018}

\newcommand\demo{% only for this example
\begin{itemize}
  \item The invoice date is \usekomavar{date}.
  \item Please pay until \usekomavar{paymentdate}.
  \item But today is the \today.
\end{itemize}%
\bigskip
}

\begin{document}
\demo

\setinvoicedate{11/03/2019}%
Change the invoice date  to \usekomavar{date}: \demo

\setinvoicedate{today}%
Reset the invoice date to today: \demo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with class option `numericaldate`:

[image]

Or with package `isodate` to format the date output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{isodate}
\isodate
\usepackage{advdate}

% Save dd/mm/yyyy for today
\newcommand*\invoicedate{}
\SaveDate[\invoicedate]

% should be possible to use a different invoicedate
\newcommand*\setinvoicedate[1]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{today}
    {\SaveDate[\invoicedate]}%
    {\renewcommand*\invoicedate{#1}}%
}

\setkomavar{date}{{\SetDate[\invoicedate]\today}}
\newkomavar{paymentdate}
\setkomavar{paymentdate}{{\SetDate[\invoicedate]\DayAfter[14]}}

% set a different invoice date
% syntax: \setinvoicedate{dd/mm/yyyy}
% if it should be reset to \today use \setinvoicedate{today}
\setinvoicedate{24/12/2018}

\newcommand\demo{% only for this example
\begin{itemize}
  \item The invoice date is \usekomavar{date}.
  \item Please pay until \usekomavar{paymentdate}.
  \item But today is the \today.
\end{itemize}%
\bigskip
}

\begin{document}
\demo

\setinvoicedate{11/03/2019}%
Change the invoice date  to \usekomavar{date}: \demo

\setinvoicedate{today}%
Reset the invoice date to today: \demo
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** regarding a comment below:

To avoid payment dates on saturdays or sundays you can load package `scrdate` and use

```
\setkomavar{paymentdate}{{%
  \SetDate[\invoicedate]%
  \ifnum\todaysnumber=6\DayAfter[16]% Saturday -> Monday
    \else\ifnum\todaysnumber=0\DayAfter[15]% Sunday -> Monday
      \else\DayAfter[14]
  \fi\fi
}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrdate}% <- added
\usepackage{advdate}

% Save dd/mm/yyyy for today
\newcommand*\invoicedate{}
\SaveDate[\invoicedate]

\setkomavar{date}{{\SetDate[\invoicedate]\today}}
\newkomavar{paymentdate}
\setkomavar{paymentdate}{{% <- changed
  \SetDate[\invoicedate]%
  \ifnum\todaysnumber=6\DayAfter[16]% Saturday -> Monday
    \else\ifnum\todaysnumber=0\DayAfter[15]% Sunday -> Monday
      \else\DayAfter[14]
  \fi\fi
}}

% should be possible to use a different invoicedate
\newcommand*\setinvoicedate[1]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{today}
    {\SaveDate[\invoicedate]}%
    {\renewcommand*\invoicedate{#1}}%
}
% set a different invoice date
% syntax: \setinvoicedate{dd/mm/yyyy}
% if it should be reset to \today use \setinvoicedate{today}
\setinvoicedate{11/08/2018}

\newcommand\demo{% only for this example
\begin{itemize}
  \item The invoice date is \usekomavar{date}.
  \item Please pay until \usekomavar{paymentdate}.
  \item But today is the \today.
\end{itemize}%
\bigskip
}

\begin{document}
\demo

\setinvoicedate{12/08/2019}%
Change the invoice date  to \usekomavar{date}: \demo

\setinvoicedate{13/08/2018}%
Change the invoice date  to \usekomavar{date}: \demo

\setinvoicedate{today}%
Reset the invoice date to today: \demo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your awesome work! Would there be an option to copy the value for `\setinvoicedate` from `scrlttr2`'s `date`-option? In this case I would have to insert the desired date only one time...

Comment: No, you can not use KOMA-Script variable `date` as argument of `\setinvoicedate`. But `\setinvoicedate` sets the value of `date` and the  depending variable `paymentdate` automatically. So you do not have to insert the date more than once! See my updated answer, I have  added some additional explanations.

Comment: Excuse me @esdd, just one more (small) thing: How can I adjust your date command so that `paymentdate`'s are always on working days? For example, if the payment date would be calculated on a saturday or sunday, it should be rounded up to monday.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple version with `datetime2` which is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237129). Please note that using the KOMA variable date is not as easy as it seemed and I introduced a separate command for that (which is `\edef`ed to allow `\today` as value). This will be used for setting the KOMA variable and doing calculations.

[image: date time calculations]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237129
\usepackage[calc,useregional]{datetime2}
\newcount\myct
\newcount\datecount
\newcommand{\myday}[2][0]{%
    \DTMsavedate{mydate}{#2}%
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{mydate}{#1}{\myct}%
    \DTMsavejulianday{mydate}{\number\myct}%
    \DTMusedate{mydate}%
}


\edef\tmpdate{2018-05-05}
\setkomavar{date}{\tmpdate}

\begin{document}
Today is \today. Please pay until \myday[14]{2018-05-05}. This is still \today. \myday[14]{\tmpdate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Dave No problem, as I mentioned in the question's comments this is only a quick and dirty adaption of another answer, not a thoroughly designed approach to address specifically this issue.