# Set date counter using advdate package

Tags: date, advdate

I searched on mathematical operations, and found several interesing results, such as [sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236078/generate-a-sequence-of-dates-in-latex), [calculations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/date-calculations), and [future](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444389/how-to-calculate-future-dates-based-on-custom-date-e-g-2018-05-05-14-days?noredirect=1&lq=1), among many others.

I am interested in an answer similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236078/generate-a-sequence-of-dates-in-latex?answertab=active#tab-top), but instead of using `\today`, I would like to set a different date.

The aim is to create a schedule with initial date, say 01/03/2019 (dd/mm/yyy), and use a command or macro, say `\nextlec` to automatically return the date 7 days ahead (27/03/2019, and so on).

I tried many approach, but didn't get desired result. Could any one give me a MWE, please? Thank you!

My code follows below. Observe that the compilation returns dates alternatedly added 7 and 8 days.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

%-> Command to set following lectures
\newcounter{lecnum}
\setcounter{lecnum}{-1}

%... Set the first lecture date
\ThisYear{2019}
\ThisMonth{3}
\ThisDay{1}

\newif\iffirst
\newcommand{\nextlec}{%
    \AdvanceDate[7]
    \iffirst
        \AdvanceDate\global\firstfalse
    \else
        \global\firsttrue
    \fi
        \section*{\today}
        \vspace{-5mm}
    }

\begin{document}
\nextlec

\nextlec

\nextlec

\nextlec

\nextlec

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us which code you have tried so far ...

Comment: The answer at the linked question sets the date to March 30, 2015, so not sure exactly what you want.  FYI, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up a test case to figure out what you actually want.

Comment: Yes, guys... I am edditing the question with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some of your code, the following just sets `\firstfalse` with the first call to `\nextlec`, otherwise it advances the date. In both instances, it just sets `\today` as a `\section`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{advdate}

%... Set the first lecture date
\ThisYear{2019}
\ThisMonth{3}
\ThisDay{1}

\newif\iffirst
\firsttrue
\newcommand{\nextlec}{%
  \iffirst
    \firstfalse
  \else
    \AdvanceDate[7]%
  \fi
  \section*{\today}
}

\begin{document}

\nextlec

\nextlec

\nextlec

\nextlec

\nextlec

\end{document}
```